# Exporting Data from SQl to Excel Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

So the admin has the choice to choose what he want to export to excel by selecting checkboxes which i stored in col[]...
here's my code for exporting

```
 session_start();
$HOST = 'localhost';
$USERNAME = 'root';
$PASSWORD = '';
$DB = 'fyp_db';

$link = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DB);

if (is_array($_POST['col'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT ";
    foreach ($_POST['col'] AS $value) {
        $sql .= "{$value}, ";
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
    $sql .= " FROM account, coursedetail, coursecategory";  
    /*echo "sql= " . $sql . "<br /><br />\n";*/
} else {
    echo "No column was selected<br /><br />\n";
}

function cleanData(&$str) { $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str); $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str); if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"'; }

$filename = "website_data.xls"; 
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
$flag = false; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) { 
    if(!$flag) { 
    // display field/column names as first row 
    echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n"; 
    $flag = true; 
        } 
        array_walk($row, 'cleanData'); 
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n"; 

        }
```

I got the error of..

**Warning**:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\project\export_successful.php** on line **28**

why? :(

Comment: Maybe your SQL is invalid. Please post your SQL query with echo().
Also you don't use mysql_real_escape_string() or something like that!

Comment: When I echo $sql; i see this sql= SELECT name, contact_number, address, date_of_birth, email, title, category FROM account, coursedetail, coursecategory

Comment: The SQL is valid but I think the problem is the mysql and mysqli as Marc B said.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up mysqli and mysql calls. The two libraries are NOT compatible and handles/statements returned by one cannot be used in the other.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
               ^--- note the 'i'
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) { 
                             ^--- note the LACK of an 'i'
```

Comment: When I add the i, it did work and manage to extract data but it says WARNING: Cannot Modify header Information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\project\export_successful.php:17) in C:xampp\htdocs\project\export_successful.php on line 26 name Joe

Comment: You cannot have ANY output before a header() call, or you get that error.